# Select one column and display values in two columns

Tags: sql

I have the following **Table Data**

[image]

I want to split column `a` into two columns like this:
**Result Data**

[image]

Person 00AB has given Paper1, Paper2, and Paper4.

What query will show in two columns which person has given the paper with 00AB.

Comment: Could you make an example output? That way it will be more clear what you are tying to do. :-)

Comment: It is easier to supply help if your data is not an image.

Comment: @Tanveer you question is not clear. Can you explain the condition for desire output?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I want to get candidate who appears in different exam papers. For example.

Candidate       |         Paper
A                                 P1
B                                 P1
C                                 P1
D                                 P2
A                                 P2
E                                 P2
F                                 P3
G                                P3
B                                 P3

In above data, A,B,C appeared in P1. D,E,A appeared in P2 and F,G,B appeared in P3.

Comment: Desired Output

Candidate       |          Other Candidate
A                                        B
A                                        C
A                                        D
A                                        E
D                                        A
D                                        E
F                                        G
F                                        B

Date should be displayed like that. A appeared with B,C,D and E in different papers and same is the case with others. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
select tableAB.a, tableP.a
from table as tableAB
inner join table as tableP on tableAB.b = tableP.b
where tableAB.a = '00AB'
and tableP.a != '00AB'
```